# RSpec - check if method was called not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to test a Facebook bot and can't figure out how to check whether a method was called. The syntax seems to be correct and when I call the method in a pry session it works as expected.

The Test:

```
RSpec.describe Postback do
  describe "initialize" do
    before do
      @fb_postback = get_postback
      @property = get_property
      @tenancy = get_tenancy(@property.id)
      @tenant = get_tenant
      @postback = Postback.new(@fb_postback.payload, @tenant, @tenancy.id, @tenancy.pin)
    end

    describe "process" do
      context "when it's a new thread and the user is not authenticated" do
        before do
          @postback.process
        end

        it "should call the tenant_returning method" do
          expect(@postback.introduction).to receive(:send_onboard_and_get_tenant_type).with(no_args)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The methods in the before block are factory methods

The Class:

```
class Postback
  attr_reader :payload, :tenant, :general, :authentication, :introduction

  def initialize(payload, tenant, ref_tenancy_id, ref_pin)
    @payload = payload
    @tenant = tenant
    @tenancy = Tenancy.find_by(id: ref_tenancy_id)
    @general = General.new(@tenant, @tenancy)
    @authentication = Authentication.new(@tenant, @tenancy, ref_pin)
    @introduction = Introduction.new(@tenant, @tenancy)
  end

  def process
    case payload
    when "new_thread"
      if authentication.state && authentication.state.current_state == "authenticated"
        general.tenant_returning
      else
        if authentication.passed?
          introduction.send_onboard_and_get_tenant_type
        else
          authentication.failed
        end
      end
    when /tenant_type=(\w+)/
      introduction.respond_to_tenant_type($1)
    end
  end
end
```

The Error:

```
Failures:

  1) Postback initialize process when it's a new thread and the user is not authenticated should call the tenant_returning method
     Failure/Error: expect(@postback.introduction).to receive(:send_onboard_and_get_tenant_type).with(no_args)

       (#<Introduction:0x007fec3f2b4930 @tenant=#<Tenant id: 51, email: nil, created_at: "2017-03-17 11:42:46", updated_at: "2017-03-17 11:42:46", fb_id: nil, first_name: nil, last_name: nil, gender: nil, locale: nil, timezone: nil, tenant_type: nil, authenticated?: nil>, @tenancy=#<Tenancy id: 61, property_id: 58, created_at: "2017-03-17 11:42:46", updated_at: "2017-03-17 11:42:46", start_date: nil, pin: "d68d054c1e8ecb69cc22">, @flow=#<Flow id: 120, name: "Introduction", created_at: "2017-03-17 11:42:46", updated_at: "2017-03-17 11:42:46">, @tenancy_tenant=nil>).send_onboard_and_get_tenant_type(no args)
           expected: 1 time with no arguments
           received: 0 times with no arguments
     # ./spec/bot/postback_spec.rb:34:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Thanks

Comment: try moving `@postback.process` after the expect clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - expectations of a method call have to happen *before* the event so I just moved `@postback.process` after the expect clause.

Thanks Jan Klimo!